# Sharepoint 2010, HTML5 video won't work on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, video, sharepoint-2010, html5-video

I created simple html page with content like:

```
...<body><video width="848" height="352" class="shown" id="videoShowcase" controls="controls" ><source src="http://myportal/PublishingImages/apple-html5-demo-tron-us_848x352.m4v" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
```

and its NOT working on ipad(ios4), while it works in chrome. If I change src attribute to "http://movies.apple.com/media/us/html5/showcase/2011/demos/" for example, it works on both(even IE in 9.0 mode).

It makes me think that the probles is 1) SP2010 access to "PublishingImages" list, but i break role inheritence, and granted anonimous access to this
2)the way SP2010 stream videos, my guess is SP2010 handlers over IIS

Any thoughts?

Comment: An M4V file likely has copyright protection on it - it's an iTunes format after all. Did you try to change the file extension to MP4? If it's not protected, it should play fine. Can't see that this has much to do with SharePoint.

Comment: DRM is not the point. I add the same page to another web application, hosted in IIS 7.5 + ASP.NET 4.0 and it's work on iPad. That mean's its a SP2010 issue, so - MIME TYPEs?

Comment: Figured out. 1)Mobile Safari requires "byte-range: bytes" from response. 2)IIS 7.5 need to be configured to work with byte-range requests. To achieve that, one's need to turn on blob cache in SP2010, or enable IIS cache. Internet tell's about another possible solutions, like writing custom httpHandler/httpModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Safari on Apple i-devices uses hardware acceleration to play videos. So instead of making request to video in the current(authenticated) context, it makes new request to the video.That request has authentication failed. So, the only "solution" to this is to store public videos allowing anonimous login.

Answer (score 0):

The file extension is irrelevant - mp4, m4v, mov etc. are all just container format extensions. The real format of the file is declared internally, and it's most likely the internal format that's the problem.

I believe that iOS will only play .h264 encoded videos. I'm not sure what avc1.42E01E is, but I'm guessing iPad doesn't support it.

I suggest you try ripping the video to an iPad compatible .h264 video using Quicktime Pro. If you find a copy of Quicktime 7 and pay the $30 license fee for pro, it comes with a bunch of easy-to-use export options for videos that will work correctly on iPad.

There are other free video rippers such as Handbrake if $30 for QTP seems a bit steep - YMMV.

Comment: The reason I mentioned flipping the extension is that if is there isn't any copy protection, the MP4 will play. AVC is a compression standard.

Comment: I've played m4vs on iPhone/iPad before. I don't think the file extension makes any difference. I realise that avc is a compression standard, I just meant that I didn't know if it was a pseudonym for one of the standards iOS supports.

Comment: Nick, to exclude incorrect file format, I copied file from [link](http://movies.apple.com/media/us/html5/showcase/2011/demos/apple-html5-demo-tron-us_848x352.m4v). So my thought now, its the difference in MIME TYPE of my site(running SP2010) and apple.com.